# Поиcк и выделение элемента Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Имеется блок в котором идут заголовок и список и так множество раз.
надо выделить тот заголовок h2 которые находится перед элементом ul в котором ссылка с классом curent
[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfox/6VN6e/)

нужно именно рещение js css и селектор :nth-child($)не подходит. так как теоретически может быть бесконечно число заголовков и списков ни как не могу врубиться как применить определённый класс к заголовку который выше списка, заранее спасибо, намутил изрядно но уж как смог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.curent').parents('ul').prev().css("font-size",'3px');
```

Доходим по родителя **ul**, стоящему перед ним элементу присваиваем **css**.

Comment: спасибо тебе мил человек